# Python Safe string templates for nested dict object

Tags: python, templates, string-formatting

I have a complex nested dict object, e.g:

```
value = { 
    'a': '100', 
    bits: {
        1: 'alpha', 
        2: 'beta', 
        3: ['31', '32', 901]
    }
}
```

I need to 'safely' format it using a template.  Meaning if the keys are not found, just silently ignore the `{}` place-holders.  The Keys might not exist, and I do not want to raise KeyErrors.  The problem is that string.Template cannot handle the same functionality that str.format does.  The str.format I used is something like:

```
"a=${a}, b1={bits[1]}, b31={bits[3]}, b9={bits[9]}".format(**value)
```

and the output should be:

```
"a=100, b1=alpha, b31=(31, 32, 901), b9="
```

I do not need fancy loops or if/else conditions.  Just simple formats with sub dicts.

What are the options I have?  I prefer to use built-ins as much as possible or a very small library.

This is not a web app, so no if possible I want to avoid loading a lib like jinja2 just for this.

Comment: As much as I like to re-invent better wheels, as much as I have time constraints and prefer to use something already tested :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write you own formatter:

```
In [1]: from string import Formatter

In [2]: value = { 
   ...:     'a': '100', 
   ...:     'bits': {
   ...:         1: 'alpha', 
   ...:         2: 'beta', 
   ...:         3: ['31', '32', 901]}}

In [3]: class YourFormatter(Formatter):
   ...:     def get_value(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
   ...:         return kwargs.get(field_name, '')
   ...: 
   ...:     def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
   ...:         first, rest = field_name._formatter_field_name_split() 
   ...:         obj = self.get_value(first, args, kwargs) 
   ...:         
   ...:         for is_attr, i in rest:
   ...:             if is_attr:
   ...:                 obj = getattr(obj, i)
   ...:             else:
   ...:                 obj = obj.get(i, '')
   ...:         return obj, first
   ...:     


In [4]: fmt = YourFormatter()

In [5]: fmt.format("a={a}, b1={bits[1]}, b31={bits[3]}, b9={bits[9]}", **value)
Out[5]: "a=100, b1=alpha, b31=['31', '32', 901], b9="
```

for Python 3, you need to add

```
import _string
```

and replace the line

```
first, rest = field_name._formatter_field_name_split()
```

with

```
first, rest = _string.formatter_field_name_split(field_name)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I need!  And Iwas just about to write my own, but your solution is much better.

Comment: @Ayman -- Glad if it helped. Also note, that this implementation can't be used universally as it doesn't deal with args for example...

Comment: This is what I get when I try this with Python 3.5 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_formatter_field_name_split'. Any solution?

Comment: I've been looking at this now.  The change is in the edited solution.

Comment: Can you possibly change the code to also be able to handle `bits[3][2]` in order to return `901`? I have nested data that I would like to parse that looks like this: `{'id': '1', 'values': {'account': [{'text': '1200 Inventory', 'value': '115'}]}}`

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to write a wrapper class that implements the dict and sequence protocols, wrapping any list or dict return values in the same class, and catch any KeyError or IndexError exceptions.

Then your call becomes `"…".format(**DefaultingWrapper(value))`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried using a default dict implementation, but failed since the nested dict are not subclasses of this new default dict class.  In other words, that will work only at the topmost level.  The implementation thus must be done at the template level.